# Is POISSON the correct family for my model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, lme4-nlme

my model is:

```
model1<-glmer(meanNOspp~VCI+treatment*size+(1|site), family=poisson)
```

I get more than 50 warning messages like this:

```
In (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L,  ... :
  non-integer x = 0.500000
```

`meanNOspp` is mean number of species, am I getting this error because poisson is not the correct family for this type of data? can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please give more details as to what you are trying to model?

Comment: Poisson variates are restricted to be integers.

Comment: If you know the $n$ behind the mean you can multiply with that, so modelling totals. Then $n$ shoukd probably be an offset (or maybe $\log n$).

Comment: This is really about the modelling error behind the error messages, so on-topic. Vote to keep open!

Comment: @Glen_b On the other hand, one might generalize the Poisson distribution to the integers by using the gamma function... For example, see here: http://blog.stata.com/tag/poisson-regression/

Comment: Can you show the plot of your response variable ? Looks like you are are doing mixed effects modeling. You could try reading the book [Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387874579) and many other authoritative books on ecology and regression modeling if you have a question on choosing right distribution for modeling ecology data.

Comment: @user777 One can do so, yes. (Actually, I thought I had listed some of my objections to some aspects of that link once already on site, but I can't seem to locate it now; but in any case my comment was to indicate the reason for the error)

Answer (score 3):

Poisson regression is appropriate if the dependent variable is a count (i.e., $y \in \mathbb N_0$). However, the error message

> non-integer x = 0.500000

indicates that your dependent variable contains real numbers.

You might consider using the *total* number of species instead (not the *mean*).

Comment: The absolute value can still be non-integer. Do you want to say the ceiling or the floor?

Comment: @usεr11852 The absolute number of species in contrast to the mean number of species.

Comment: Cool. I think that *total* will be more accurate. I see your what you mean. +1.

Comment: @usεr11852 Agreed, I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the mean number of species cannot be an integer. Poisson regression is used to model count data and it is maybe your problem.

Maybe, a log-Normal regression can be more adequate instead of your Poisson regression:

```
model1<-lmer(log(meanNOspp) ~ VCI+treatment*size+(1|site))
```

One can have two equal means, for two different totals. I think to model the mean and the total are two different things, especially if it is not the same number of staff for each individual mean meanNOspp in the regression. So it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I believe that using totals is not the best use of the data. I decided to go for log-normal regression. I finally decided to use the following model:
species1<-lmer(log(meanNospp)~VCI+treatment*size+(1|bloque))

Comment: CORRECTION: I also tried using gaussian, but it said that glmer is deprecated, so I needed to use lmer direclty. So the following two models work:
model1<-lmer(log(meanNospp)~VCI+treatment*size+(1|site))
model2<lmer(meanNospp)~treatment*size+(1|site))

Then I ran AIC values to choose the best model, not sure if this is a correct thing to do, since one model uses a log-normal regression and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Actually, the log-normal model tries to model y~exp(x). Thus, if it fits better the data than the model y~x does, it has a better log-likelihood and a lower AIC. So, using AIC to compare these models is not meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a modified Poisson regression for the totals. This will be correct if a Poisson model is correct for the individual counts. It would probably be better then to model the individual counts, if you have them). Suppose the $N$ (number of obs) behind your mean (meanNOspp). Multiply that with its $N$ to get the total, and then include $\log N$ as an offset in the model equation. Then it should work.

Another advantage with this approach is that, if it turns out that
the poisson assumption do not work, maybe you have overdispersion, then you can just use the same mean specification with another error distribution (such as negative binomial), as long as you keep the log link function (or you could use a `quasipoisson` family).